# HP Fortify analysis results, system() command injection

Tags: c++, linux, security

I am trying to write c++ code that calls a command in a linux command line and I am using HP Fortify to check for exploits in the code. Can someone familiar with HP Fortify source analyzer tell me if it is possible to use a system() linux call in c++ code without getting the low threat warning from HP Fortify (low : Command Injection: semantic)? Is there still a threat of command injection if I hard code the input to the system() function while writing out full paths to the programs and/or files in the call? I don't understand a more secure way of giving it input than hard coding it in. Should I be ignoring the system() function and find another way to call commands from my c++ code to the linux command line?

Edit: I tried using execv() instead of system() to call a program but it still gives me the command injection warning for using execv().

Comment: Environment variables can also be part of the attack surface, e.g: as in the shellshock vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

In a word "No".

The HP Fortify semantic analyzer detects potentially dangerous uses of functions and APIs at the intra-procedural level. Basically a smart GREP. So it essentially just looks for the words "system()" and "execv()" in your code. It rates them as a "Low" because it found no path where an attacker could influence the string command that system() will use.

If, however, the code had user input concatenated in a string that was passed to system(), the Data Flow Analyzer should pick that up as a Critical Command Injection.

Think of the Low Semantic findings as "Security for Dummies" ;-)